# Click a link using HtmlUnit in google scholar

Tags: java, htmlunit

I'm using HtmlUnit and trying to search in google scholar then get a bibtex item by doing the following:

1.go to google scholar.

2.type the name of the file i want to search.

3.click "cite" link, then a small box will appear.

4.in the small box i want to press "import to bibtex" and get the text.

for example you can look at this page and try : https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=internet+of+things+for+smart+cities&btnG=&hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5

I was able to access search page but i couldn't complete the other steps.
This is my code

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
    HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("https://scholar.google.com/");

    HtmlInput searchBox = page.getElementByName("q");
    searchBox.setValueAttribute("internet of things for smart cities");


    HtmlButton googleSearchSubmitButton = page.getElementByName("btnG");
    page = googleSearchSubmitButton.click();

    HtmlAnchor anchor = page.getAnchorByName("Cite");
    page = anchor.click();

    System.out.println(page.asText());

    webClient.close();
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a start to what you're trying to do:

```
    WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
    webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
    webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);

    HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("https://scholar.google.com/");

    HtmlInput searchBox = (HtmlInput) page.getElementById("gs_hp_tsi");
    searchBox.setValueAttribute("internet of things for smart cities");

    HtmlButton googleSearchSubmitButton = page.getElementByName("btnG");
    page = googleSearchSubmitButton.click();

    HtmlAnchor anchor = page.getAnchorByText("Cite");
    anchor.click();

    webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(5000);

    HtmlAnchor linkBibTex = page.getAnchorByText("BibTeX");

    TextPage neededPage = linkBibTex.click();

    System.out.println(neededPage.getContent());

    webClient.close();
```